# Unable to connect to pooling module

Tags: node.js, connection-pooling

I am trying to connect to pooling module but it is not connecting. 
Below is my code:

```
  var express = require('express')
     , routes = require('./routes')
     , signup = require('./routes/signup')
     ,login=require('./routes/login')  
     , http = require('http')
     , path = require('path')
     , cal=require('./routes/calculate')
     , db = require('./routes/db')
      ,pool = require('./routes/pooling')
       , ejs = require('ejs')
     , moment = require('moment')
     , mysql = require('mysql')
     ;

       var app = express();

      pool.connect();
       pool.initializepool(10);
```

I get below error :

> cannot find the module ./routes/pooling.

I am trying to implement connection pooling.
Could anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

See the pooling examples from the `mysql` module readme.  Remove the require for pool (not needed and not a route).

```
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'example.org',
  user            : 'bob',
  password        : 'secret'
});

pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
});
```